# When to refresh data in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm not sure this question is strictly limited to iOS, as it's more of a general application-design question on data integrity. But at the moment, I'm getting into iOS and have hit a "best practice" wall.

If we use the Twitter app as an example. We have one tab for our timeline and one tab for our profile. So (to keep things *very* simple) each one is a View Controller, backed by an object (model). I tweet on the timeline VC, then I head on over to my profile tab. Both `viewDidLoad` methods have already ran, so the data that was loaded to draw the UI is currently stale. The "count" of my tweets is now out of date. In the iOS world, what is the best methods/approaches to keeping the VC model data synced with the backend?

Is it on a time interval? Or network requests in the `viewWillAppear` method? Is it event driven, ie. when I tweet in one VC, and it's been saved in the backend web service, I notify any VCs that care that there's a new tweet

I'm not 100% sure this question will have an "answer" in the SO sense, but I'm just trying to understand what's the done thing in the iOS world (as someone who comes from the web development world).

Comment: A combination of pull to refresh, and a 60 second refresh `NSTimer` works well. (Change 60 seconds to whatever you like). If a pull to refresh is occuring, remember to invalidate the `NSTimer`, as theres no need to have two refreshes occuring at the same time. Re-initialze the `NSTimer` after the refresh completes.

Comment: @troop231 and that timer, would that run globally? ie. not just when the View is on screen? So it'd be updating in the background?

Comment: When you need to or think you should.  If you receive some sort of notification of updates you can wait for a notification.  And either delay after receiving the first notification or have a minimum time between refreshes so you don't refresh constantly when stuff is pouring in.  If you receive no notifications then you just have to use a timer, and it's probably best to make is user-adjustable, within limits.

Comment: Is this a tab bar based app? Have a `NSTimer` for each UITableViewController that can get data from the internet.

Comment: Chances are that the twitter app also refreshes itself due to receiving a push notification ... This would be the ideal but push notification delivery is not guaranteed by apple and can't take X amount of time to send/receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a loose sketch of some things our team has done on a networking application that might give you insight for your own architecture.

At the level of the VC (in viewWillAppear) we typically have multiple NSNotificationCenter observers that will call whatever update methods you need to run after a network update call.

Firing off these notifications is some network listener that lives on a background thread. It's job is to wait for responses from the backend server (typically JSON blobs) that contain updates to the data model. I believe ours has a time interval that will periodically phone home and check to see if we have new things to update.

Note you will necessarily have to devise an asynchronous solution for network calls as the passing/receiving of data packs can be unreliable, and take time, and thus should be computed in the background. You'll also need a way to handle data loss and other errors between server and device. And of course in order to see UI updates, you'll need to switch back to the main thread when updating the VC.

Assuming a some change of state (i.e. new message), then it makes the call to get the new data, which then fires off an NSNotification (with a new payload of info), that goes to the observer on the VC.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned with viewWillAppear, UIViewControllers are a core building block of iOS apps. They have a lifecycle to follow to help with things like this scenario.

You have many options, but the best practices would to make calls on the viewWillAppear method and then reload your table views, collection views, etc.

Another thing you can add is push notifications on data change. You can now send a push notification with the "content-available" option that is silent and sent to your app when data changes on the backend. Then your app can refresh data only when needed.

I would stay away from timers. They will keep making network request and keep the radio from going into a battery saving idle mode.